# Image is not displaying after successfuly uploading it?

Tags: laravel

Image is not displaying in the nav bar after uploading it to the database. I think there is something wrong with the file storage path, but I don't know where I am making a mistake.

This is the image storage path

```
$image = $request->file('picture')
$path = $image->store('public/images');
$yourModel = new User();
$yourModel->name = $validateData['name'];
$yourModel->email = $validateData['email'];
$yourModel->password = $validateData['password'];
$yourModel->image = $path;
```

Comment: Please add your question blade view how you are displaying your images. Also check your default storage disk path if you save in storage folder. You need link it into public holder by artisan command: `php artisan storage:link`

Comment: I have already linked to it.

Comment: This is the blade view.                                                                                                                                            <img class="rounded-circle w-25 h-20" src="{{ asset('storage/images/' . Auth::user()->image) }}" alt="User Image">
                <span>{{ Auth::user()->name }}</span>

Answer (score 0):

you store the image in the public iamges and in blade you say show the iamge form the storage/images that is incorrect you need to change the ima html to  `<img class="" src="{{ asset('images/' . Auth::user()->image) }}">`